# Define %ROWTYPE with fewer columns than the actual table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I declared **emp_obj** as rowtype of **emp_table** (which has **x** number of columns), however I want **emp_obj** to have **x** minus **y** columns (i.e. fewer colunms). How do I go about?
My code is:

```
DECLARE emp emp_table%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN   
    SELECT name,
           surname
    INTO emp_obj 
    FROM emp_table 
    WHERE emp_ID='89545585' 
    AND ROWNUM=1; 
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the fields to store the columns in, e.g.:

```
DECLARE emp emp_table%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN   
     SELECT name,
            surname
     INTO   emp_obj.name,
            emp.surname
     FROM   emp_table
     WHERE  emp_ID='89545585'
     and    ROWNUM=1; 
END;
```